# Performance improvement python

Tags: python, performance

I want to improve this code for performance. It is taking around 1.5 seconds to run, but I am trying to get something better. I have tried approach (A) but it is taking more time. May I have any help, please?

This is the code:

```
def approx_pi2(n=10000000):
    val = 0.
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        val += 1./k**2
    return (6 * val)**.5
```

This was my approach (A):

```
# (sum(1./k**2 for k in range(1,10000001))*6)**.5
```

Comment: Generators are optimized for memory usage, not running time.

Comment: The best performance improvements you'd get for something like this would be algorithmic. For example, using a series with faster convergence. Given that you're working with limited-precision floating point, though, the most simple improvement would be `import math; return math.pi`.

Comment: Why are some people so mean? Someone criticizes my question giving -1, but it doesn't even give a reason. This is my doubt. If someone doesn't want to answer, do not be interested in diminishing it as well!

Comment: Thank you  user2255757, cheapener, and  user2357112 for your time and attention! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as getting better performance from small changes, on my system replacing k**2 with k*k nearly tripled the performance:

```
def approx_pi2(n=10000000):
    val = 0.0
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        val += 1.0 / (k * k)
    return (6.0 * val) ** 0.5
```

but as always, YMMV